# Unity 360 viwer user sphere or skybox?

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox, 360-panorama

I have some issue I need to build scene 360 photo-viewer/panorama and put here the buttons. Firslty, I worked with skybox and when I change user position the buttons are not on the right place, the angle of view was changed. For example you can see a blue square imagine this is a button. But if user will change the position(move player left), the button will cover other place. In general, I need that the button should be strickly connected to particular place.
[image]

I created 360 sphere but the images are squashed like [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1204600/gear-vr-photo-inside-sphere-deformed-texture.html) .

Can you help me please to improve:

1. Sphere appearance 
   or
2. Skybox - how can I put buttons that when I change user position buttons will keep the same position

Thanks!

Comment: use a high poly sphere. Primitive sphere from Unity is not right for this. Regarding buttons I didn't really get what you are saying. can you show some screenshots for that

Comment: Ok thank you very much! will try high poly... As for skabox and button I added image and provide more explanation. The main point that using skybox I cannot connect button to the particular place. Let me know please if it is clear? Thanks

Comment: I case of skybox and prespective camera, it is very difficult to do this. I would suggest you to go with inside-sphere and place the buttons close to sphere mesh.

Comment: Thanks very much, created high poly this looks perfect!!!